# Why shared libraries are implemented using GOT (Global Offset Table)?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have looked up tons of articles about GOT, dynamic linking and shared libraries. But I still can't figure out why shared library can't be implemented by dynamic linker directly modifying addresses of "mov" instructions in ".text" section to "fix" symbol relocations?

Answer (score 1):

This would be much less efficient. Here's what comes to mind, there might be more:

- this breaks code sharing across different processes which load same shared library
- there will typically be lots of calls that require updating (rather than just updating single address in GOT)
- loader would need to remap code pages as writable and then map them again as read-only; that's `2*num_pages` system calls so quite slow
- static linker would need to reserve maximum number of bytes in call instructions to accomodate for largest possible address (8 on x86_64) which would increase code size

You also loose lazy symbol resolution.

Comment: You can change the protection flags on multiple pages at the same time. But text relocations trigger copy-on-write, and they are generally frowned upon. I don't think many architectures even have 64-bit absolute or relative call instructions, so you need something like GOT indirection if you have more than 2 GiB of code in total anyway.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer Thanks, I was sure I missed something.

Comment: @yugr, the main reason is not that.  Changing addresses is something that is to be done only onche at load time... or it can be done per page, as the references are required.  See my response.

Comment: @LuisColorado There are so many different reasons that it's hard to see which one is main really...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the `.text` section of a shared library is indeed *shared* (by all processes using that shared object) and if you modify it, it gets modified in *all instances* of it (so you are actually modifying the code of other processes).  This is the reason shared libraries have to be compiled in `PIC` (Position Independent Code) mode, because all instances of the same shared text load at different addresses, depending on the final executable that is going to use them.

Only in systems where the kernel (e.g. freebsd allows this) Allows `.text` segments to load in *copy on write* mode this is permissible. But think in the overhead of copying a full page of code for process private access only because you have touched (only once) several pointers on it.

Normal binaries have their code *read only* or *execute only*, so you can share the same pages of code between all processes that use them.  Think that the kernel normally doesn't use even swap space to store those pages, as it can go to the executable file to reload the page in case it gets *swapped out* (It isn't, the page is just discarded from memory)

Comment: " it gets modified in all instances of it" -- this is wrong due to copy-on-write.

Comment: @employedRussian, I tried to explain the reason for implementation of text segments as read-only.  The copy-on-write feature came later and then **it is possible to modify** the `.text` segment (or the library text segment) Did you understand else?

Comment: The question is about Linux and `GOT`. Linux *always* allowed relocatable `.text`, and `COW` didn't come "later". The "all instances" part your answer makes sense in the context of Windows95, but not anything later than that. So it's not "*the* reason".

Comment: probably... but modifiable text is the target of the question.  Unmodifiable text is previous to linux, as it is implemented as told in my answer since UNIX v7 (and earlier)  Relocation of code is the problem, and this is what makes GOT in use here.  Modifiable text is not an alternative if shared text is to be used and no copy-on-write feature is available.  If you insist in having the reason... ok... no problem... You are right.. I never said the opposite.  And linux not always allowed modifiable text. The introduction of modifiable text is well posterior to the birth of linux.